# Excel - Average unique values

Tags: excel

I am trying to get an average of the values in my table with unique "IDs".

ID  value

A   10

B   20

C   30

C   30

A   10

E   20

A   10

For the above data, I would expect the average of unique Ids to be 20.

(10+20+30+20)/4.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. May I know what have you tried or any guess the solution may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell `I2`, write

`=AVERAGE(IF(MATCH($B$2:$B$8,$B$2:$B$8,0)=ROW(ZZ1:INDEX(ZZ:ZZ,COUNTA($B$2:$B$8))),$C$2:$C$8))`

then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Which

- `MATCH` function returns the index which match the id
- `ROW` function returns the row index
- if the `MATCH` equals `ROW`, where id appears first time
- `IF` function returns the value where id appears first time
- `AVERAGE` function returns the average value of what id appears first time

[image]

Comment: This works great! Thank you.  Can you clarify, what ZZ1 and ZZ:ZZ are used for so that I can use this on a different dataset.

Comment: @ryan  `ROW(ZZ1:ZZ100)` returns an array {1,2,3,...,100}.  Since there are seven ids, you need `ROW(ZZ1:ZZ7)`.  Here I use `INDEX(ZZ:ZZ, COUNTA(B2:B8)) to get `ZZ7`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `{=SUM(IF(A1:A7<>"",1/COUNTIF(A1:A7, A1:A7), 0))}` for counting distinct IDs. From here there should not be a problem to compute the average.